# Alert.Dialog builder code unreachable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-dialogfragment

I was trying to make a dialog Alert in android studio. But here it shows code is unreachable. Please help me out.

```
public class Mydialog extends DialogFragment
{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder theDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    theDialog.setTitle("Sample Dialog");
    theDialog.setMessage("hello world");
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    theDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            toasty("Clicked Ok");
        }
    });



}

public void toasty(String str)
{

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's because you `return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);` before the end of the method. Put this line to the end of `onCreateDialog()`.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I meant delete this line and add to the end:

```
return theDialog.create();
```